# Run script from netbeans toolbar button

Tags: button, netbeans, toolbar

I've created a new toolbar button using the tutorial: [Create Toolbar Button](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/71/nbm-google.html)
However, it doesn't explain how to run a script using the button. Starting with "Creating the Toolbar", it goes in a different direction than what I need.

I just need a very, very simple action of running a shell script in the netbeans terminal.

How do I have it run this script from the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you linked to, you need to put your logic in GoogleAction.java. Specifically this section of code is where you need to handle the button press.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO implement action body
}
```

If you want to run a script in there, you will need to write the java to do it like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/script.sh", "arg1", "arg2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("TestEnvValue", "value");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! I ended up using the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(RunScript.sh) command, but that was the right place to put it.